# SqlAlchemy 'datetime.datetime' is not mapped

Tags: python-3.x, sqlalchemy, scrapy

I'm using Scrapy to grab domains and their creation date using the Whois module. I am then adding them to a MySQL database using SqlAlchemy but I get the below error when adding the creation date to the database because the data type is `<class 'datetime.datetime'>`

```
sqlalchemy.orm.exc.UnmappedInstanceError: Class 'datetime.datetime' is not mapped
```

I tried to convert the date into a string but then I get another error.

pipelines.py:

```
class SaveDomainsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        domain = Domains(**item)
        domain_item = item['domain']
        domain_whois = whois.query(domain_item)
        creation_date = domain_whois.creation_date


        try:
            session.add_all([domain, creation_date])
            session.commit()
```

models.py

```
class Domains(Base):
    __tablename__ = "domains"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    date_added = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), server_default=func.now())
    domain = Column('domain', Text())
    creation_date = Column('creation_date', DateTime(timezone=True))
    #creation_date = Column('creation_date', Text()) -- I also tried this
```

Comment: Why do you add `creation_date` to the session?

Comment: To add the domain creation date along with the domain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a rookie mistake in my original code.
As I initiated an instance of the class "Domains", I had to refer to it when populating the columns which I had originally missed. The working code can be found below.

```
class SaveDomainsPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        engine = db_connect()
        create_table(engine)
        self.Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)


    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        session = self.Session()
        domains = Domains() #initiate instance of Domains class.
        domains.domain = item['domain'] #Add the item "domain" from Items to DB
        domain_whois = whois.query(domains.domain)
        domains.creation_date = domain_whois.creation_date #Add the creation date to DB

        try:
            #save the instance which saves both the domain item and creation date.
            session.add(domains) 

            session.commit()
```